# why C# ThreadLocal does not work as expected with Task in TPL?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

cannot understand an example in a book from apress talking about a misused case of threadlocal with task construct in TPL.

Why isn't it become 10000 in number as expected results?

Could anyone give a more detailed explanation on the program flow of below program for which line execute instantly and some lines async in time? the sequence and order of execution?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Listing_05 {

class BankAccount {
    public int Balance {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Listing_05 {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // create the bank account instance
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount();

        // create an array of tasks
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[10];

        // create the thread local storage
        ThreadLocal<int> tls = new ThreadLocal<int>(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("Value factory called for value: {0}",
               account.Balance);
            return account.Balance;
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // create a new task
            tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() => {

                // enter a loop for 1000 balance updates
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                    // update the TLS balance
                    tls.Value++;
                }

                // return the updated balance
                return tls.Value;

            });

            // start the new task
            tasks[i].Start();
        }

        // get the result from each task and add it to
        // the balance
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //added by myself to see any hints but still cannot have insights
            Console.WriteLine("task {0} results {1}", i, tasks[i].Result);
            //end of my editing

            account.Balance += tasks[i].Result;
        }

        // write out the counter value
        Console.WriteLine("Expected value {0}, Balance: {1}",
            10000, account.Balance);

        // wait for input before exiting
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Results in a computer using 8 cores i7 cpu, shall be 8 threads. Run Several times and below are 2 out of many executions.

[image: 1st execute]

[image: 2nd execute]

Do not understand how the programs work and behave in this way

Comment: See https://particular.net/blog/the-dangers-of-threadlocal

Comment: Yes, I just did google on above link before asking above questions but maybe I am a novice on this thread topics so I can hardly understand the situation why the program behave like this. Up to now, my understandings is ThreadLocal is data local to thread only. Task is declarative which you describe the task to be done by unknown worker thread. It is unknown the thread-local initialized data will crash due to some out of 10 tasks reuse same thread data being modified already in some of 10 tasks? could someone describe how the execution of this example is... some line should be deferred to run?

Comment: @Cuda, you have two `account.Balance` in your value factory. Both entitled to return different results.

Comment: Tasks normally run on a thread provided by the threadpool.  Biggest feature of the threadpool is that it re-uses threads.  So two tasks can easily end up using the same ThreadLocal variable, a bug in the provided example.  The AsyncLocal class provides a useful substitute.

Comment: There is no guarantee how much thread will the scheduler use for your code

Comment: So the number of threads to be used by scheduler is no guranteed? I have wrong concept that the thread assigned to do the tasks is based on my hardware CPU i7 with 4 cores 8 thread...... Or in some way the scheduler will first check the hardware and see most appropriate number of threads to be created to do "Tasks".

Comment: @Hans Passant Currently, I do not have knowledge of AsyncLocal since the book focus on TPL but not async until I go google for this aspect, I could easily find there is some books solely devoted to Async... Actually I am a novice, but would like to study more in these area of threads and async execution rather than traditional sequential execution of code line by line. Where could I start for a solid ground for concept? These areas seems such a big topic...

Answer (score 4):

Tasks provide a mechanism to run code concurrently. This does not mean they will necessarily run on separate threads or even if multiple threads are used that they will not be reused.

Do not try to use thread local storage with Tasks at all.

Alternative storage options are to use a closure within the tasks's lambda function, or create a class and put data on that class and use a method of that class as the Task's callee. I personally feel this is a lot cleaner anyways.

Hans Passant also mentioned `AsyncLocal` in comments which would be worth researching (I haven't used it myself so can't comment).

Comment: So you mean it could be either 1 thread to do Tasks concurrently or multiple threads to do Tasks concurrently, no guarantee on reuse of thread, so do not use thread local storage which is only local to a single thread? What should be used for Tasks for data storage?